# How do I put structs or tuples in state of rust iterators?

Tags: rust

I'm very new to Rust. I'm trying to use Advent of Code as an excuse to learn it. I'm currently an Elixir programmer so I use map/reduce all day.

I'm struggling to do the same thing with rust. I'm sure I could just bail on the iterators and just plow through it with `for loops` but I'd prefer not to.

It looks like `fold` is something very similar to `reduce` but I can't figure out how to use any state more complicated than an integer.

```
input
.chars()
.map(|c| c.to_digit(10).unwrap())
.fold(initial_state, |state, &x| {
    let Day1{sum: sum, prev: prev} = state;
     Some(Day1{
        sum: sum,
        prev: prev,
     });
 })
```

I'm getting lots of compiler errors about non-matching types.

```
.fold(initial_state, |state, &x| {
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected (), found struct `Day1`

let Day1{sum: sum, prev: prev} = state;
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected (), found struct `Day1`
```

Why does it expect `()` which is nothing (I think). I'd like to understand the error, but if there is a better way to have state maintained in a loop I'd like some help with that as well.

Comment: Please review how to create a [MCVE]. You haven't provided the definition of `Day1`, `input`, or `initial_state`. FWIW, you can just do `let Day1 { sum, prev } = state;` and `Some(Day1 { sum, prev })`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is very clear if you look what you are doing. Let me explain.

First, it is good idea to have the Rust docs in touch. Looking at the [`std::iter::Iterator::fold`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.fold) method there gives you it's signature:

```
fn fold<B, F>(self, init: B, f: F) -> B where
    F: FnMut(B, Self::Item) -> B,
```

There are 3 arguments: `self` which you don't touch because you use this method as a struct method and not static method, `init` which you set to `initial_state` and a fold function as `f`. At a glance you may say everything is correct but your usage mismatches this prototype because of excess semicolon at the end of the fold function - your whole expression returns `()` in that case and so the compiler tries to match the return type of your fold function with the `init` argument's type and it is unable to do that. The solution is very simple: remove the semicolon by changing

```
let Day1 { sum: sum, prev: prev } = state;
Some(Day1 {
    sum: sum,
    prev: prev,
});
```

to this:

```
let Day1 {sum: sum, prev: prev} = state;
Some(Day1 {
    sum: sum,
    prev: prev,
})
```

In Rust (as in most functional languages), the last expression is a return expression. In your case, you returned nothing but if you remove the semicolon, you will return the `Some(Day1 { sum: sum, prev: prev })` expression which has a type of `Option<Day1>`.

After fixing this, you may have another problem: mismatching `Day1` and `Option<Day1>` which will occur because you have different types again: `initial_state` of type `Day1` and the fold function which returns `Option<Day1>`. The solution is to use the same type in any of these places, for example, make `initial_state` of type `Option<Day1>` or return `Day1` object from the fold function and so everything will compile. Again, having the Rust documentation in touch gives you a [clear example of the `.fold` usage](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#examples-25).

Comment: *`initial_state` of type `Day1` and the fold function which returns `Option<Day1>`* — how do you know what the type of `initial_state` is? OP hasn't provided it.

Comment: @Shepmaster simply from the error message: 
    > ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected (), found struct `Day1`